# mostrar imagen base64 mientras me cargan mis otra imágenes con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, imagen, base64

tengo un ecommerce en el que muestro las imágenes  de los productos, cada 8 imágenes, cuando hacen scroll al final de la pagina se muestras 8 mas y así sucesivamente, mi problema básicamente es que cuando voy a mostrar las 8 imágenes nuevas, la pagina hace un parpadeo mientras cargan las imágenes nuevas y lo que quiero es ver si las puedo pasar a base 64 mediante la url de la imagen para que esta se muestre mientras carga la otra.

lo e intentado hacer de un una función para pasar a base 64 pero es asíncrona y en este  caso necesito que todo sea síncrono para que cargue al mismo tiempo.

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
 callback(reader.result);
        
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();

}



 for (let i = 0; i < data_consult_productos.length; i++){  


toDataUrl(data_consult_productos[i].imguno, function(myBase64) {

 img_uno = '<div class="carousel-item active"><img src="'+ myBase64 +'" class="d-block w-100" alt="'+ data_consult_productos[i].nom_pro +'"></div>';
                                                            
});


    A.innerHTML = img_uno; 
    

}
```

bueno la función toDataUrl es con la que paso a base64 pero se ejecuta asíncrona entonces no me sirve por que me da el base64 luego de que se ejecuta el for,  lo que necesito es que me lo ejecute inmediato, que realice el ciclo for y me vaya pasando imagen a imagen a base64 para que se muestren de inmediato cuando haga el innerHTML

de igual forma si tienen una mejor forma de hacerlo soy todo odios, soy muy nuevo en esto y aun me cuesta,  lo que quiero básicamente es que cuando este cargando mis imágenes no se vea ese parpadeo que hace antes de mostrar la imagen, quiero que se muestre ya todo cargado y listo.

Comment: Desconozco si aplica de la misma forma, pero en js con node.js he trabajado con funciones asíncronas, para la problemática que presentas primero crear una función que contenga lo que quieres se ejecute, que esa función sea asíncrona, esto es importante, si no es asincronía no podrá esperar la función que ejecuta, y por ultimo un `await` antes de la función que quieres esperar quedaría `await toDataUrl(data_consult_productos[i].imguno, function(myBase64) {...` es importante este dentro de una función asíncrona o no te dejara hacerlo. Prefiero comentar esto porque podría estar equivocado.